# Knockout.js: Toggling Visibility Of Multiple Dom Elements Using Multiple Buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, binding, knockout.js

I have a js fiddle ([located here)](http://jsfiddle.net/Halcyon/jqL45/) that I want to mimic using knockout.js. The idea is that each button has a corresponding div tag. If the corresponding div tag is visible, it should hide when the button is clicked. Otherwise, it should show. If any of the other non-corresponding divs are visible, they should hide and then show the corresponding div. How can I mimic this jQuery version using knockout? The js fiddle for the knockout version is [located here](http://jsfiddle.net/Halcyon/A7XY3/2/). It works but it still seems really verbose. It seems like there should be a way to make it more dynamic and reduce the amount of work. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
<style type="text/css">
    .text { background-color: lightgray; }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var viewModel = {
            showHide1: ko.observable(false),
            showHide2: ko.observable(false),
            showHide3: ko.observable(false),
            toggle1: function () {
                this.showHide1(true);
                this.showHide2(false);
                this.showHide3(false);
            },
            toggle2: function () {
                this.showHide1(false);
                this.showHide2(true);
                this.showHide3(false);
            },
            toggle3: function () {
                this.showHide1(false);
                this.showHide2(false);
                this.showHide3(true);
            }
        };

        ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
    });
</script>

<div id="text1" class="text" data-bind="if: showHide1">Text 1</div>
<div id="text2" class="text" data-bind="if: showHide2">Text 2</div>
<div id="text3" class="text" data-bind="if: showHide3">Text 3</div>
<br />
<br />
<button id="button1" type="button" data-bind="click: toggle1">Button 1</button>
<button id="button2" type="button" data-bind="click: toggle2">Button 2</button>
<button id="button3" type="button" data-bind="click: toggle3">Button 3</button>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I propose using a function that returns the handler.  I find it's an essential method to writing sane Knockout code.

## Basic

#### [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/A7XY3/3/)

We can simplify the HTML to this.  It checks what should be `showing`, has our buttons change what is `showing`.

```
<div id="text1" class="text" data-bind="if: showing() === '1'">Text 1</div>
<div id="text2" class="text" data-bind="if: showing() === '2'">Text 2</div>
<div id="text3" class="text" data-bind="if: showing() === '3'">Text 3</div>

<button id="button1" type="button" data-bind="click: show('1')">Button 1</button>
<button id="button2" type="button" data-bind="click: show('2')">Button 2</button>
<button id="button3" type="button" data-bind="click: show('3')">Button 3</button>
```

Our `ViewModel` is also simplified.  First, we turn it into a function, for easier extensiblity.  Our `showing` is simply a string value.  `show` is the meat of our code.  It returns a function that sets `showing`.

This way, we could rename the elements from `1`, `2`, and `3`; to `main`, `about`, and `contact` without touching the JavaScript.

```
ViewModel = function(){
    var self = this;

    self.showing = ko.observable('');
    self.show = function(what) {
        return function(){ self.showing(what); };
    }
};
ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel);
```

## Transition Animation

#### [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xhvym/)

To use jQuery's slide in/down we can use [code provided](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html) by KnockoutJS's documentation.  This is the JavaScript code with comments removed:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.slideVisible = {
    update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
        var value = valueAccessor(), allBindings = allBindingsAccessor();
        var valueUnwrapped = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(value); 
        var duration = allBindings.slideDuration || 400;
        if (valueUnwrapped == true) 
            $(element).slideDown(duration); // Make the element visible
        else
            $(element).slideUp(duration);   // Make the element invisible
    }
};
```

To put this into the HTML, simply replace the `if` binding with `slideVisible`.

```
<div id="text1" class="text" data-bind="slideVisible: showing() === '1'">Text 1</div>
<div id="text2" class="text" data-bind="slideVisible: showing() === '2'">Text 2</div>
<div id="text3" class="text" data-bind="slideVisible: showing() === '3'">Text 3</div>
```

Comment: That is an awesome demo! Any ideas on how to use jQuery's slideUp and slideDown functions in your answer?

Comment: @Halcyon, I added sliding transition.

Answer (score 5):

You could use the `template` binding with a dynamic template name like:

```
<div class="text" data-bind="template: { 'if': current, name: current() }"></div>
<button type="button" data-bind="click: toggle1">Button 1</button>
<button type="button" data-bind="click: toggle2">Button 2</button>
<button type="button" data-bind="click: toggle3">Button 3</button>

<script id="text1" type="text/html">text 1</script>
<script id="text2" type="text/html">text 2</script>
<script id="text3" type="text/html">text 3</script>
```

with a view model like:

```
var viewModel = {
    current: ko.observable(''),

    toggle1: function () {
        this.current("text1");
    },
    toggle2: function () {
        this.current("text2");
    },
    toggle3: function () {
        this.current("text3");
    },
};

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

Sample here: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/Zh9Qy/

Note that in KO 2.3, you would not have to pass `current()` for the `name` option and could just pass `current`, as it will now be unwrapped properly.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a viewModel that contains the id of div to show. This property will be set accordingly of the button on which you click.

View model:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var ViewModel = function(){
        var self = this;
        self.onClick =function(data, event) {
           var element = event.target.id.replace('button', 'text');
           self.shownElement(element)
        };
        self.shownElement =ko.observable(null);

    };

    ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
});
```

View :

```
<div id="text1" class="text" data-bind="visible: shownElement() == 'text1'">Text 1</div>
<div id="text2" class="text" data-bind="visible: shownElement() == 'text2'">Text 2</div>
<div id="text3" class="text" data-bind="visible: shownElement() == 'text3'">Text 3</div>
<br />
<br />
<button id="button1" type="button" data-bind="click: onClick">Button 1</button>
<button id="button2" type="button" data-bind="click: onClick">Button 2</button>
<button id="button3" type="button" data-bind="click: onClick">Button 3</button>
```

[**See fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/9F4rs/)

I hope it helps.